# in calculator's text box how to assign the value which is in upper line to the 1st variable and value in lower line to the 2nd variable?

Tags: vb.net

I am making a calculator and want my text box to show the value (assigned to first variable at run time) along with the operator[+,-,*,/] in upper line.

Then the value entered in the second line should be assigned to the second variable.

Then when I press the equal(=) button the required operation should be performed i.e add the first variable and the 2nd variable.

I have done a little but it doesn't provide the right answer for example:

- when I enter 3 and click the Add(+) button the cursor goes down in the lower line
- when i enter 5 and press equal button, text box shows 6 in result instead of 8

and so on.

Here is the code

```
Private Sub ButtonAdd_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButtonAdd.Click
    Operand1 = Val(TextBox1.Text)
    TextBox1.Text = Operand1 & "+" & Environment.NewLine & Operand2
        TextBox1.Focus()
        [Operator] = "+"
End Sub

Private Sub ButtonEqual_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButtonEqual.Click
    Dim Result As Double

    Operand2 = Val(TextBox1.Text)
    Select Case [Operator]
        Case "+"
            Result = Operand1 + Operand2
            TextBox1.Text = Result

        Case "-"
            Result = Operand1 - Operand2
            TextBox1.Text = Result
        Case "*"
            Result = Operand1 * Operand2
            TextBox1.Text = Result
        Case "/"
            Result = Operand1 / Operand2
            TextBox1.Text = Result
    End Select
    TextBox1.Text = Result
End Sub
```

Comment: You should define Operand1 a level higher. Now, ButtonEqual_Click doesn't see it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using the wrong text box:

```
Operand2 = Val(TextBox1.Text)
```

should be

```
Operand2 = Val(TextBox2.Text)
```

Comment: I don't see your variable declarations, but if you are declaring them at the form level, your code actually does work.

Comment: Public Class Form1

    Dim Operand1 As Double
    Dim Operand2 As Double
    Dim [Operator] As String

Comment: here is the declaration                                                               [code]Public Class Form1

    Dim Operand1 As Double
    Dim Operand2 As Double
    Dim [Operator] As String[/code]

Comment: I get enter 3 and click add and I get "3+0", then overwrite that with 5 and click the equal button and I get 8.  Seems ok.

Answer (score 0):

```
[code]
```

Operand2= val(textbox1.text)
[/code]
Should be
    [code]
Operand2= val(textbox1.lines(1))
[/code]